# How to get Spain resident's discount on travel?

Tags: tickets, spain, ferries, residency

I'd like to be able to receive a discount offered for [ferry](http://www.navieraarmas.es/es/inicio) and [airplane](https://www.bintercanarias.com/) tickets for [Spanish Residents.](http://www.tuescapada.eu/subvencion-residente-vuelos-canarias-baleares-ceuta-melilla/#axzz2rFpup1At).

Is it possible to get them available to me without living in the country?

Comment: Can you update the links so that they point to actual documentation of benefits?

Comment: The benefits vary. On the ferry company site just select your travel and you will get both prices for residents and for standard passengers. For the airplane site you will have to select if you’re a resident to see the individual benefit. The document (the last link in my question) explains that the benefit should be about 50% of the price.

Comment: You want to get the Spanish resident discount, without being a Spanish resident.  Is that correct?

Comment: Well, the idea was to become a resident from abroad. I could use the address of a friend’s house who lives there.

Comment: @erik The question was rewritten in this way becase of 2 reasons: 1.  Obtaining Residence is a question about immigration which is off topic.  2.  Questions about obtaining Municipal Registration, which requires proof of residency, without having one or providing a false one would be illegal and against Stack Exchange policy.  So the question as you have edited it became off topic just as your original question which was closed and then deleted by you and reposted again as this question.

Comment: I just tried to answer gerrits comment. Sorry for that. I do not want to do something illegal. I only want to know if I can get these residents’ benefits for my travel to Spain/Canary Islands for my next trip. I can not see anything illegal, when my plan is to stay there for vacation for about three months (at a friend’s house, visiting him).

Comment: @erik At issue is that you're not in the country and are attempting to see if it is possible to get Municipal Registration without being there.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it related to practices nominally in disagreement with the law.

Comment: Reminds of me the Seinfeld episode where George was trying to get a funeral discount on his plane tickets :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done. The Spain resident's discount is a help the Spanish government gives to the people living in Balearic Islands, Canary Islands, Ceuta or Melilla to fly within the country.

The idea of this subsidy is to alleviate the difficulty (on money and time) to access the rest of the country.

This said, what you pretend to do is to fake the rule. This subsidy is paid with the taxes of the people and you are trying to cheat them.

More info in [ResidentsAny questions?](http://www.iberia.com/gb/faqs/residents/) in Iberia website.